# How to get the width and height of a dynamically loaded image?

Tags: jquery

How do I get the width and height of a dynamically loaded image?

```
<img id="thumb_320" src="dscn6691_thumb_320.jpg">
```

Comment: You can't. It's just an anchor tag. It possesses no knowledge of the image itself. You'd have to load the image, then grab the dimensions of javascript.

Comment: If you are ok with ditching IE6 & 7 (and probably 8 too), you could use the Image() object.  I think you can load it without rendering it, and thereby get the dimensions of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using the `Image` object. I'm honestly not sure of compatability though.

so some code might look like:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){
    alert('Width: ' + img.width +', Height: ' + img.height);
}

img.src = 'http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png';
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EQdxw/2/

Comment: just add an id if you need one. You have to have a src otherwise there will be no image loaded.